# Importing/Migrating an API from Local Repo/ Environment to Other Environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I tried to export/import an API from one environment to other environment, where as Exporting is working fine but facing issues while Importing an API from Local/Environment

I have used api-import-export-2.6.0.war with APIM-2.6.0,

Command used to Import api: apimcli import-api -f G:/Petstore_1.0.0.zip -e dev

Error importing API Reason: C:\Users\RAVIKU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apim130994779\Petstore_1.0.0\Meta-information\api was not found as a YAML or JSON
Exit status 1

Comment: do you see any errors in the log? please extract the zip and list down the file names inside it.

Comment: No.. I didn't find any errors other than that, 
api.json
swagger.json are the two files which are existing inside the .zip file

And I have also tried converting the JSON into YAML and tried importing but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the API Import and Export web application is compatible with the WSO2 WUM. Meanwhile please check with [that](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Migrating+the+APIs+and+Applications+to+a+Different+Environment) also.

Comment: Web application is upto date... tried with the new version, where as exporting is working fine.. if not even exporting wouldn't work fine.!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving the import API command the API file name as `<environment>/file_name`; where `<environment>` is the environment where the zip file exists[1].

```
apimcli import-api -f <environment>/Petstore_1.0.0.zip -e dev
```

[1].https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Migrating+the+APIs+and+Applications+to+a+Different+Environment#MigratingtheAPIsandApplicationstoaDifferentEnvironment-ImportinganAPI

Comment: yes! I tried, even that was unsuccessful. 
used commands: apimcli import-api -k -f dev/Petstore_1.0.0.zip -e test --preserve-provider=false /// apimcli import-api -k -f G:/Petstore_1.0.0.zip -e test /// apimcli import-api -k -f dev/Petstore_1.0.0.zip -e test